# Proper way to match bytes in a stream? - verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm fairly new to hardware design and I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I'm working with a 64 bit wide stream that also has End Of Packet and Start of Packet signals. I need to find a particular byte sequence at an offset from SOP. The goal is to pass the stream to another module, and every time SOP is asserted, a match signal will tell the next module whether or not the byte sequence will be found in the incoming packet.

I think I need to shift the signal into a large shift register (16x64 to fit the search space) and do the comparison on those slices. But then it seems I would also need shift registers for SOP and EOP to keep those signals in sync with the data (match would be asserted along with SOP). Am I on the right track, or is there a better approach?

Comment: Is the 64 bit stream input serially or in parallel? Is the location of the byte sequence fixed or can it be anywhere in the 64 bytes? Is the start/end of packet always wrap a single 64 bit packet, or does the size/offset vary? What kind of clocks do you have (single or multiple)? How fast do you receive data (1 packet/clock, or 1 packet per *N* clocks)?

Comment: @Tim I get 64 bits every clock cycle (serial). SOP is asserted one clock before the first 64 bits, and EOP is asserted on the last 64 bits. Packets are a multiple of 64 bits. The location of the sequence is fixed. There's only one clock, and the packet length varies. Most packets will be many clocks, but the sequence will be within the first 16 cycles.

Comment: You say the location of the sequence is fixed, but at the same time you say it will be 'within' the first N cycles. Is it always at the same place, or isn't it? Can I say "The sequence will always be at byte *N*, *M* clocks after SOP". Or does M or N vary?

Comment: @Tim Sorry, the 6 byte sequence compares against bytes 120-125, which would be on the 15th clock after SOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case I think you're onto the right idea. If the downstream module must know if the match exists before receiving the SOP, then I would just make a 16 or 17 stage pipeline of all the data and the two control signals.

If that's too many registers for some kind of area constraint, you might consider using a small ram to hold the packets while you're waiting to do the check.